# how to override mailboxer mailer

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, mailboxer

I have customized the notification_mailer.rb in my mailers folder in order to use Mandrill API, but mailboxer ignores it and keeps using the regular smtp method. I have done the same thing with Devise but  Devise has a config.mailer in its initializer filer. Not Mailboxer.

Below is the mailer file. Thanks for pointers.

```
class Mailboxer::NotificationMailer < Mailboxer::BaseMailer
#Sends and email for indicating a new notification to a receiver.
#It calls new_notification_email.

def mandrill_client
  require 'mandrill'
  @mandrill_client ||= Mandrill::API.new ENV['MANDRILL_APIKEY']
end


def send_email(notification, receiver)
  new_notification_email(notification, receiver)
end

#Sends an email for indicating a new message for the receiver
def new_notification_email(notification, receiver)
  @notification = notification
  @receiver     = receiver
  set_subject(notification)

  template_name = "new-notification-email-fr"
  template_content = []
  message = {
    to: [receiver.send(Mailboxer.email_method, notification)],
    subject: t('mailboxer.notification_mailer.subject', :subject => @subject),
    merge_vars: [
      {rcpt: receiver.send(Mailboxer.email_method, notification),
        vars: [
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
    mandrill_client.messages.send_template template_name, template_content, message
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I used wrong naming convention. It should have been

```
class MailboxerNotificationMailer < Mailboxer::BaseMailer
```